# UPDATE with multiple WHERE and SELECT condition - MySql

Tags: mysql, php

So, I have two tables `ativos` and `colaboradores` and they are linked by `id_colaborador (FK)` on my update page, I'm able to change the `id_colaborador` but instead of changing the ID I want to write the name that match to that ID but I think I need multiple `WHERE` conditions and `SELECT`, may anyone help me out? Thanks!
I have the following code to update

```
$sql = "UPDATE ativos  SET ativo = ?, comentario = ?, data_aquisicao = ?,
                           localizacao = ?, fabricante = ?, modelo = ?,
                           imei = ?, numero_serie = ?, ativo_sap = ?,
                           anexo_a = ?, evento = ?, data_evento = ?,
                         SELECT id_colaborador FROM colaboradores 
                               WHERE nome = ? AND WHERE id_ativo = ?";
```

Comment: Please rephrase the question.  I'm lost, too.  Which row of `ativos` do you want to change?  Is it `id_ativos=?`?  Where should `id_colaborado` be stored?  The text says you want a "name", but the `SELECT` is fetching an `id`.  Etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query (while removing PHP code and formatting) looks like

```
UPDATE ativos  
SET ativo = ?, 
    comentario = ?, 
    data_aquisicao = ?, 
    localizacao = ?, 
    fabricante = ?, 
    modelo = ?, 
    imei = ?,         
    numero_serie = ?, 
    ativo_sap = ?, 
    anexo_a = ?, 
    evento = ?, 
    data_evento = ?, 
    SELECT id_colaborador 
    FROM colaboradores 
    WHERE nome = ? 
    AND WHERE id_ativo = ?
```

It is syntactically incorrect. Use [Multiple-table UPDATE syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html). Final query must look near

```
UPDATE ativos a
  JOIN colaboradores c 
/* next line maybe wrong, question is not clear */
    ON a.id_ativo = c.id_colaborador 
SET a.ativo = ?, 
    a.comentario = ?, 
    a.data_aquisicao = ?, 
    a.localizacao = ?, 
    a.fabricante = ?, 
    a.modelo = ?, 
    a.imei = ?,         
    a.numero_serie = ?, 
    a.ativo_sap = ?, 
    a.anexo_a = ?, 
    a.evento = ?, 
    a.data_evento = ?
/* next line maybe wrong, question is not clear */
WHERE c.nome = ?
```

Answer (score -1):

If I've understood your question correctly, you can join the table and set the column to be the name instead of the ID:

UPDATE a
SET a.id = b.Name
FROM TableA a
    INNER JOIN TableB b ON a.ID = b.ID

Comment: The question is tagged as MySQL-related. "Syntax Error" guaranteed.